# (Ionic/Cordova) PermissionDeniedError for getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc

so I'm working on an app that uses WebRTC and I'm at a point where I want to bang my head against the table. I'm having an issue with getUserMedia, which always returns **PermissionDeniedError** when I run it on my phone (Android 6.0.1).

The app has these permissions set in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

The app does request storage, camera and voice permissions on runtime and I have installed cordova-diagnostic-plugin, which verifies the app has these permissions.

I've also tried setting the following HTML header as recommended by someone:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="media-src: 'self' mediastream: blob:;">
```

I'm running **Cordova 6.3.1** and **Ionic 2.0.0**. (I also have installed the Android Support Repository 38 and Support Library 23.2.1 as required by cordova-diagnostic-plugin).

For reference, the getUserMedia code I'm using is:

```
if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, gotUserMedia, reject);
}
```

The Android target SDK version is set to 23 (for Android 6).

Has anyone got any ideas that could help? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to enable storage permission manually from settings if you are using "6.0.1".

Answer (score 1):

Okay, crisis averted. Turns out it was my fault, I was running the app with --livereload on ionic (to get a console output), which ran it via non-ssl local server which getUserMedia doesn't like xD

I built the app via "ionic build android" and installed it manually on my phone, and it works fine now :)